# Timestamp conversion failure in SAS Hive

Tags: hive, sas, timestamp

Its a hive in SAS.
Its working in a particular case.
For example.

```
proc sql;
connect to hadoop;
select dt, unix_timestamp(dt, "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy') from log
disconnect to hadoop;
quit;
```

Its result is not problem. `Sun DEC 01 17:00:00 KST 2019, 122233....`

But when I use substring

```
select dt, unix_timestamp(dt, "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy') 
   from log where substring(dt, 25, 4)='2019'
```

timestamp value is turn to null.

And

```
create table log_temp as
select dt, unix_timestamp(dt, "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy') from log
```

Its also make it null

Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The year part of the date time representation in the `log` table starts at position `25`, not position `20`

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
1234567890123456789012345678

where substring(dt,25,4) = '2019'
```

should work

Comment: Thank you. But it was a typo and actually wrote it down properly.
Nevertheless, the timestamp value continues to be null